# How to make Go append work inside a range loop

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have this function which takes an unknown amount of input from a struct:

```
func GetAllXXXByQueryFilters(ctx context.Context, filters ...XXXFilters) ([]XXX, error) {
    var allKeys []*datastore.Key
    var xxx []XXX
    for _, filter := range filters {
        query := datastore.NewQuery("XXX")
        if filter.Foo != "" {
            query = query.Filter("foo =", filter.Foo)
        }
        if filter.Bar != "" {
            query = query.Filter("bar =", filter.Bar)
        }
        keys, err := models.DSClient().GetAll(ctx, query, &xxx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        allKeys = append(keys) // PROBLEM HERE
    }
    for i, key := range allKeys {
        xxx[i].ID = key.ID
    }
    return xxx, nil
}
```

The problem is that allKeys will override previous query results. I have previously overcome the problem by doing:

```
keys1, err := models.DSClient().GetAll(ctx, query1, &xxx)
keys2, err := models.DSClient().GetAll(ctx, query2, &xxx)
keys = append(keys1, keys2...)
```

But I wanted my GetAllXXXByQueryFilters to be more sophisticated and avoid duplicated code, and now I can't seem to figure out how I can store the keys from the `for _, filter := range filters` loop and then append them all afterwards. So I was hoping that maybe there was a smarter way to do/replace the `allKeys = append(keys)` line so that it doesn't override previous keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to the slice like this:

```
allKeys = append(allKeys, keys...)
```

The first argument to append is the slice. The remaining arguments are the elements to append to the slice.  The append function returns the new slice.